# instanceof evaluates to true in Node 4 but not Node 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, prototype-chain

When I execute this in Node 4, the last statement evaluates to `true`, however in Node 6 it evaluates to `false`.  Why?

```
F = () => {};
F.prototype = {};
Object.create(F.prototype) instanceof F;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably a bug in Node 6.x. Consider the following:

```js
const Foo = () => {};
Foo.prototype = {};
const foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
// false in Node 6, true in Chrome
console.log(foo instanceof Foo);
// true in Node 6, true in Chrome
console.log(Foo[Symbol.hasInstance](foo));
```

The first two logs should return the same value, because the instanceof operator is defined to call and return the `@@hasInstance` method of `Foo`, if present ([`§12.9.4`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-instanceofoperator)). What is more interesting, node throws TypeError in the following case, while `false` is expected, as `Foo` is not callable ([`§7.3.19`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinaryhasinstance)):

```js
const Foo = {
  "prototype": {},
  [Symbol.hasInstance]: Function.prototype[Symbol.hasInstance]
};
const foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
// throws in Node 6, false in Chrome
console.log(foo instanceof Foo);
// false in Node 6, false in Chrome
console.log(Foo[Symbol.hasInstance](foo));
```

PS

Node v6.2.2 (64-bits) was used for the tests on a Windows system.

Comment: Thanks for verifying the behavior.  I opened a Node issue here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7592

Comment: @wprl I think they might just implemented an older draft of the spec, or mixed the es5 and the es6 behaviour. Just curiousity: Do you really rely on this behaviour?

Comment: I don't use `instanceof` all that often but I do sometimes… I'd like the next version of deco, a mixin module I wrote, to maintain support for using `instanceof` like this.